# Sending a response after a finalized transaction - Stripe

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, stripe-payments

After a long discussion with ChatGPT, I managed to write code that redirects the user to the Stripe payment page and then captures an event when the transaction is successfully completed.
The problem is that my `fetch` request has already received a response from the `/checkout` endpoint and is not waiting for a response from `/webhook`. And I would like my API to return a properly generated response after successfully finalizing the transaction. What am I doing wrong?

First, I send a request to the `/checkout` endpoint, which takes care of generating the payment link and sending it back:

```js
fetch('http://localhost:3001/checkout', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        items: [
            {
                id: 0,
            },
        ],
    }),
})
    .then((res) => {
        if (res.ok) return res.json();
        return res.json().then((e) => console.error(e));
    })
    .then(({url}) => {
        console.log(url);
        window.location = url;
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

This code when I press the button redirects me to the Stripe payment page.

Endpoint `/checkout`:

```js
app.post('/checkout', async (req, res) => {
  try {
      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
          payment_method_types: ['card'],
          line_items: req.body.items.map(({id}) => {
              const storeItem = storeItems.get(id);
              return {
                  price_data: {
                      currency: 'pln',
                      product_data: {
                          name: storeItem.name,
                      },
                      unit_amount: storeItem.priceInCents,
                  },
                  quantity: 1,
              };
          }),
          mode: 'payment',
          success_url: `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/success.html`,
          cancel_url: `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/cancel.html`,
      });
      console.log(session.url);
      res.json({url: session.url});
  } catch (e) {
      // If there is an error send it to the client
      console.log(e.message);
      res.status(500).json({error: e.message});
  }
});
```

I connected StripeCLI to my server using `stripe listen --forward-to localhost:3001/webhook`. Now I can capture the successful transaction event using the `/webhook` endpoint, but I have no way to return `The transaction was successful` to the client:

```js
app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {
  const event = req.body;

  if (event.type === 'checkout.session.completed') {
      res.send('The transaction was successful');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After the suceesful payment the customer should be redirected back to your website. Where you can create success page.

```
success_url: `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/success.html`,
```

If you want to get some data back from the Strapi after the paymant is successful page you can add this

```
success_url: `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/success.html?&session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`
```

At the succes page you just deconstruct the data. And do whatever you want with them :)

If you deconstruct the object for example like this: (Next.js)

```
const stripe = require("stripe")(`${process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY}`);

export async function getServerSideProps(params) {
  const order = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(
    params.query.session_id,
    {
      expand: ["line_items"],
    },
  );
  const shippingRate = await stripe.shippingRates.retrieve(
    "shr_1MJv",
  );

  return { props: { order, shippingRate } };
}


export default function Success({ order, shippingRate }) {
  const route = useRouter();
```

Yo can log out the whole object to see whats inside

```
console.log(order);
```

If the payment was sucessfull you should get in prop variable: payment_status: "paid"

Comment: Thanks for comment. I understand that on the success page I need to read the `session_id`, send a query to Stripe to confirm that the transaction represented by the `session_id` has been finalized. Am I correct? How can I check on the React client side whether the transaction represented by` session_id` has been finalized?

Comment: If you deconstruct the object, you have multiple info there.

Comment: In the object there is variable called → payment_status
If the customer has payed for your product the value of the var should be: payment_status: "paid"

Comment: added the code to the official answer bro

Answer (score 0):

Stripe will automatically redirect the client to the `success_url` that you specified when you created a Stripe session.

You can use the webhook for saving the order in the database for example, but not to redirect the client.